vscode format space inside curly braces
In VSCode, there are extra spaces after and before curly braces, I want to remove the extra spaces inside braces,
from
import { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

to
import {StrictMode} from 'react';
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';

I added the following in the settings.json file, but it works when I didn't install prettier extensions when save file, but it doesn't work after installing prettier extension.
"javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false
"typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false

Also, after this setting, when I write import {crete and press TAB key, the auto import function always inserts the spaces,
how can we remove the spaces when press TAB key and format the file?

Remove or disable prettier.

Thank you. But prettier is very usable for project, this is why asked this thread to keep prettier and also remove extra space.

The settings
"javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false
"typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false

are for the VS Code formatter, not for prettier.
The corresponding prettier settings are
bracketSpacing: false

as documented in https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#bracket-spacing
